# Regex Match for Domain Name in Django Model

Tags: python, regex, django, model

I have one table, which looks like:

```
class Tld(models.Model):
    domainNm = models.CharField(validators=[ RegexValidator('^[0-9]^[a-z]','yourdomain.com only','Invalid Entry')], max_length=40)
    dtCreated = models.DateField()
```

for domainNm - I want to validate on any entry that looks like:

- domain.com
- 1domain.com
- domain1.com

It has to follow this way : `<domainname>.[com|biz|net]` etc and be alphanumeric.

How do I do this on the model level of a django model?

Thanks

Comment: That's an invalid regex. **^** matches the beginning of the string. It doesn't make sense to have it in there twice unless separated by **|**. Anyway, it's not clear what you want to match. Are you trying to make sure the string begins with an alphanumeric character, or that the whole thing is alphanumeric with dots and possibly "http://" at the beginning, or what? Please try to be specific and give examples of what you want the regex to match and what you want it to reject.

Comment: Please see updated question. Sorry for confusion

Comment: So are you now saying that you *don't* want to match if it begins with "www" or "http://", are do you still want to match if either of those precede the domain? Also, do you want to limit it to a single dot, or do you also want to match if there are subdomains? The regex `^[a-z0-9]+\.(com|biz|net)$` will validate that the string is in the form you described in the revised question, but I'm not sure if that's what you really want. Should `http://domain.com` and/or `subdomain.domain.com` match or fail?

Comment: The regex you state is right, but how could I make the domain extension (e.g. com, biz, net) be more dynamic to say only allow alpha characters and only 4 of them at most ? e.g. com, biz, net would all work, but allow something like info without having the regex spell out the domain extensions?

Comment: Also, please state your comments in a question

Comment: What do you mean by "state your comments in a question"? If you meant to say in an *answer*, the reason I didn't post it as an answer is that it wasn't clear to me what you want to accomplish. It still isn't - please answer the following: (a) Should `http://domain.com` pass or fail validation? (b) Should `subdomain.domain.com` pass or fail validation? (c) Should `www.domain.com` pass or fail validation? Once I know that, I can post an answer.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity: (a), (b), (c) all fail. Only alphanumeric domains e.g. somedomain.com, 1somedomain.com, somedomain1.com, with domain extensions > 1 and > 4 are valid. So, somedomain.cools fails since the extension is > 4

Comment: I think I figured it out : ^[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{1,4}$

Comment: but please do write your answer, since you got me on the right track

Comment: If you want only letters in the TLD. I thought you wanted it all alphanumeric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To recap the clarifications above: You want to match only domains with a single alphanumeric label and a TLD of up to 4 characters, eg. "domain.com" or "someotherdomain.info" or "345xyz.pdq1" but not "subdomain.domain.com", "http://domain.com", "www.domain.com", or "345xyz.abcde". This regex will do it:

```
^[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]{1,4}$
```

Comment: This is very limited. ie: express.co.uk would break and so www.* domains (even though you mentioned, I'd rather insist on that).

Answer (score 15):

If you want to validate HTTP URL's, forget the regex and use the [builtin validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.URLValidator).

If you want only domains without any protocol, try:

```
def full_domain_validator(hostname):
    """
    Fully validates a domain name as compilant with the standard rules:
        - Composed of series of labels concatenated with dots, as are all domain names.
        - Each label must be between 1 and 63 characters long.
        - The entire hostname (including the delimiting dots) has a maximum of 255 characters.
        - Only characters 'a' through 'z' (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits '0' through '9'.
        - Labels can't start or end with a hyphen.
    """
    HOSTNAME_LABEL_PATTERN = re.compile("(?!-)[A-Z\d-]+(?<!-)$", re.IGNORECASE)
    if not hostname:
        return
    if len(hostname) > 255:
        raise ValidationError(_("The domain name cannot be composed of more than 255 characters."))
    if hostname[-1:] == ".":
        hostname = hostname[:-1]  # strip exactly one dot from the right, if present
    for label in hostname.split("."):
        if len(label) > 63:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("The label '%(label)s' is too long (maximum is 63 characters).") % {'label': label})
        if not HOSTNAME_LABEL_PATTERN.match(label):
            raise ValidationError(_("Unallowed characters in label '%(label)s'.") % {'label': label})
```

**Usage:**

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator

field = models.CharField(_('host name'), max_length=255, validators=[URLValidator])
```

or

```
field = models.CharField(_('host name'), max_length=255, validators=[full_domain_validator])
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer as it points out the existence of validators - the OP asked for a top-level domain (not full domain) validator though.

Comment: This validator will allow a hostname like: domain (without tld)